# How to inject the Store to my ember component

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli, store

I am in the situation where i need to inject the store to my component , at least i think this is my need.

This is the situation:

I have component , the code itself does not really matter but i paste it for better understanding:

```
//components/masonry-plugin.js
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({
  didInsertElement : function(){
    this._super();
    Ember.run.scheduleOnce('afterRender', this, this.afterRenderEvent);
  },

  afterRenderEvent : function(){
    var $grid = this.$('.grid').masonry({
      itemSelector: '.grid-item',
      percentPosition: true,
      columnWidth: '.grid-sizer'
    });
    // layout Isotope after each image loads
    $grid.imagesLoaded().progress( function() {
      $grid.masonry();
    });  
  }
});
```

This is his own template

```
<div class="grid">
    <div class="grid-sizer"></div>
    {{#each model}}
        <div class="grid-item">
          <img {{bind-attr src=imgLink}}>
        </div>
     {{/each}}
</div>
```

This template is imported in an other template photography.hbs by `{{masonry-plugin}}`

The question is, since in photography.hbs i have access to the module `imgLink`, because in the route photography.js i create the module consuming the Flickr API, how can i make the module accessible also to the template in `{{masonry-plugin}}` ?

Hope the explanation is clear

Here also the model img for clarification

```
var img = DS.Model.extend({
    imgLink: DS.attr('string')
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, for this you don't need the store in your component.

Just pass the img Model instance or the imgLink string to your component:

```
{{masonry-plugin model=model}}
```

(this depends on you having `img` available on your calling context)

If this does not help try to provide a simple example with an [ember-twiddle](http://ember-twiddle.com/) or at least the code of your `photography` `route`, `controller` and template.

Comment: This is correct components should work with the DDAO (Data down action up)

Comment: It does not work out for me, i have reproduced the case with model, photography route, component and component template. Look here https://gist.github.com/Mannaio/a90fcf8feebc05d4dc70

Comment: This is ember twiddle https://ember-twiddle.com/a90fcf8feebc05d4dc70?numColumns=1&openFiles=component.masonry-plugin.hbs%2C,

Comment: thanks, i would like to understand what i am doing wrong

Comment: {{masonry-plugin imgLink=img.imgLink model=model}} this was missing i did not pass the model, i correct the answer

Comment: @Koala7 well, yeah, in your case give the model. But I would strongly recommend to give it a better name then `model` inside the component!

Answer (score 2):

You need only one line in component to [inject](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.inject.html#method_service) store or other services there:

```
import Ember from 'ember';
const { service } = Ember.inject;

export default Ember.Component.extend({
    store: service(),
    foo: service('store') // if you dont want to name property same as service
});
```